# Identity server 4 device code flow user code lenght

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

Is there any way to change user code length for device flow authorization on identity server 4?
Regarding to [documentation](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/options.html)
they describe the settings for device flow as follows:

> The user code type to use, unless set at the client level. Defaults to
> Numeric, a 9-digit code.

User code length by default is set to 9-digit which is a pretty long code and really not friendly for the user experience.

Comment: IS the user code not generated by the device itself? and not by IdentityServer? But I might be wrong here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement your own generator. The default generator is NumericUserCodeGenerator and generates a random number from 100000000 to 999999999.

To use another generator you need to implement and register in DI this interface: IUserCodeGenerator. This interface has two properties and one method:

- UserCodeType (string): Asign a name for your custom type of code.
- RetryLimit (int): If the generated code has already been generated for another flow, another code will be generated until the code is unique or this number of times is reached. If it fails to generate a unique code in this number of attempts, an InvalidOperationException will be thrown. If you reduce the length or the complexity of the code you should increase this value.
- GenerateAsync: return your generated code here.

Configures your clients with your UserCodeType value in its property whit the same name (Client.UserCodeType), otherwise they will continue using the default generator.